# Why isn't this child react component rendering?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get a child component to render in react and it's not rendering. If I write the actual JSX composed in the child component in the parent, it renders, Why is that? The examples in the documentation show that this is possible, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/309969/

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() { 
  return(
   <Rectangle />
    );
  }
}

function Rectangle(){
    return (
        <div className="Rectangle">
          <square />
        </div>
   );
}

function square(){
    return (
        <div className="square">
       </div>
   );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
 .Rectangle {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #222;
   height: 760px;
   width: 40px;
 }

 .square {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: green;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<!Doctype>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The end result should show a dark grey rectangle, with a 20x20 pixel green square affixed to the top left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your components starting with a capital letter.

```
function Square(){
    return (
        <div className="square">
       </div>
   );
}

function Rectangle(){
    return (
        <div className="Rectangle">
          <Square />
        </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to render the child component "square" then change the name square to Square  and also change the function name square to Square. Component name always needs to start with Capital Letter. Otherwise it will not render.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. Components name should start with capital letters.
2. In your fiddle you are using the `logoutBox` `className` but you wrote a `.square` css class.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Rectangle />
    );
  }
}

function Rectangle() {
  return (
    <div className="Rectangle">
      <Square />
    </div>
  );
}

function Square() {
  return (
    <div className="square">
    </div>
  );
}
    
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
 .Rectangle {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #222;
   height: 760px;
   width: 40px;
 }

 .square {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: green;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```